# Why it is impossible to make qobject_cast for QPropertyAnimation

Tags: c++, qt

Here is the QPropertyAnimation' creation code:

```
    void CustomGraphicsScene::addAnimation(AnimatedPixmapItem* item)
    {
        auto propertyAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation { item, "SpriteFrame" };
        connect(propertyAnimation, &QPropertyAnimation::destroyed, this, &CustomGraphicsScene::deleteAnimation);
        propertyAnimation->setDuration(1000);
        propertyAnimation->setStartValue(0);
        propertyAnimation->setEndValue(10);
        propertyAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

And here is the slot, where I'm trying to cast QPropertyAnimation:

```
    void CustomGraphicsScene::deleteAnimation()
    {
        auto propertyAnimation = qobject_cast<QPropertyAnimation*>(sender());
        if (propertyAnimation) { // Always false
            // Some code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) not only does a casting but also verifies that the QObject is still alive using the QMetaObject, for example if you print `propertyAnimation->metaObject()->className();` at the time of building the object it will return `QPropertyAnimation`, but in the slot associated with destroyed `sender()->metaObject()->className()` returns `QObject`.

My recommendation is to use finished, change the delete policy and delete it in the slot.

```cpp
void CustomGraphicsScene::addAnimation(AnimatedPixmapItem* item)
{
        auto propertyAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation { item, "SpriteFrame" };
        connect(propertyAnimation, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, this, &CustomGraphicsScene::finishAnimation);
        propertyAnimation->setDuration(1000);
        propertyAnimation->setStartValue(0);
        propertyAnimation->setEndValue(10);
        propertyAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::KeepWhenStopped);
}

void CustomGraphicsScene::finishAnimation()
{
    auto propertyAnimation = qobject_cast<QPropertyAnimation*>(sender());
    if (propertyAnimation) { // Always false
        // Some code
        propertyAnimation->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I thought QObject will be destroyed after `destroyed` signal, Qt documentation says "This signal is emitted immediately before the object obj is destroyed".